# Node Express APP 1 to N (with MongoDB)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, database

we are developing a big node app with express and MongoDB. We are trying to get the best performance, because we will have multiple clients (maybe 100+) running on the same server.

We were thinking in a one-to-n APP, one instance, one database and multiple clients accessing their domains.

I want to know what is the best settings for this scenario (one server, multiple clients) to performance and development

1. One instance, one database (clients data would be identified by a `company` ObjectId on the entry and clients would access a domain or subroute)
2. One instance, multiple tables (or databases, what is the best?)
3. Multiple instances, multiple tables
4. Any other ideas?

On the first setting, the developers will always worry about the current company and this can bring limitations to the app

On the second setting, the concern will continue but the company will not  interfere on the database entries (more clean model)

On the third setting (maybe the best for development) only one company will be treated and brings a lot of possibilities, but may bring performance issues (all instances will run on a single server)

Other settings I have not thought of can be better.

Notes:

We are using the mongoose library

I have some experience with WordPress and i like the way themes and plugins are created for it. We are trying to achieve a level of performance similar to Wordpress with PHP (several Wordpress running on a server efficiently)

sorry about bad english

Comment: approximately how many clients are we taking about in here? Did you try load balancing?

Comment: I updated the question with the clients number. No, how can i do it?

Comment: Its all depends on how you design the application. you can design the application to minimize the requests to the server and do possible logics in the client side. do a research on load balancing. I personally recommend you to run multiple application instances with multiple data base for fail safe application and you can use a load balancer to redirect requests to different servers accordingly.

Comment: But multiple node instances can cause performance loss? is there any benchmark or examples of how other companies are doing it?

Comment: I'm not talking about running multiple node instances in a one server. Run multiple node instances in separate servers. then if one server fails, other servers can take up the load and keep serving the clients. same time this will improve the performance.

Comment: But on a scale of 100 apps, can node or any tool optimize this case? If so, is it automatic or do I need to do something? How much processing power would it take to run this case? thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to manage multiple instance as you can create a company collection and in that collection you can store every single company and then you just need to create a reference of all these values in users.Please make sure that you have made unique index on company collection.It is really easy handle such scenarios in RDBMS(mysql).

And one more thing you can also run multiple mongod client on same instance by just changing the port and if you are looking for that sort of solution then you can do that as well.

**Please note following things before using mongo:-**

Please use mongo only if you have over TB's of data because that doesn't make any sense to use mongodb for some mb's or gb's of data.

Use of indexes is must in mongo if you want maximum performance.

Mongo stores all the indexes in main memory and if the indexes size is more then memory that it start swapping of indexes which is really costly and hence please make sure that you have different servers for your application and your db.

I still says it would be better to use RDBMS if you don't have TB's of data to deal with.
Why this approach:-

Let me give you a scenario.
You have 100 companies and with in 100 companies you have 1000 users for each of the company. i.e. you have 1L records in your user collection.Now i want to delete a single user  or i want to update a user or i want to fetch a user from a single company then i don't need to traverse my complete database as i can make a index on my user collection using user-id and company id(compound index)  or even i can make a simple filter query on company id.

For index please read this
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/

And btw we are not saving company id as an object instead i am saving only the value of **_id** from company collection.

Comment: What you are saying is to use the first setting right? One DB, with data identified by company ID. But this way, i always need to worry about the company ID on every query, how can i solve this? We have been developing this way for a year, and sometimes this brings some limitations.

Comment: that just a string and it could be max to max 1000 or 10000 or 100000. But  there is no point of using a NoSQL db for such a small data.

Comment: For now we will keep using MongoDB (changing right now is not possible), but we will think about change to a SQL DB. About the company identifier, its a string, but still is a field to pass to the query and to be tested. But I Still don't know why this is the best approach of the 3 i've mentioned. And i don't know how to use it this way without affect the application

Comment: @Maxwells.c  Answer is modified why this is best approach

Comment: if you still have any doubt..then lets take it to chat

Comment: If you don't mind, I want to ask you some more questions, how can I contact you?

Comment: Please contact me on hangout.my email id is atul.agrawal9911@gmail.com